# Vulkan C++ Wrapper

Tags: wrapper, vulkan

I know OpenCL has C++ wrappers that wrap the corresponding `clRetain` and `clRelease` calls in their constructors and destructors that it inherits from `detail::Wrapper<T>` template. (http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1detail_1_1_wrapper.html)

Im wondering if Vulkan has the same/ similar c++ wrapper available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better served with the [resources list](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Khronosdotorg/blob/master/api/vulkan/resources.md#libraries).

There are at least four projects that could be considered a C++ wrapper incl. the officially adopted `vulkan.hpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Did You look at [Vulkan-hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp)? It's a C++ wrapper for Vulkan objects and functions. It provides unique handles for Vulkan objects. They don't have typical wrapper constructors - they are created with separate, dedicated functions (like *createBufferUnique()*). But they automatically call appropriate destruction/freeing functions in destructors.

Comment: It's part of Vulkan now. Great thing.